# Creating assocations between objects with RestTemplate on Spring Rest Data (HATEOAS)

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm struggling with manipulating objects (which are JPA entities) on a Spring Data Rest API via RestTemplate.

I've got a tree structure where Genre's have parents and children of other Genres (it's the [itunes genre tree](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=26))

Creating an object is fine:

```
URI selfLink = restTemplate.postForLocation(api+"/genre", genre, Collections.emptyMap());
```

Creating an association with it is not quite so easy. If I try to PUT a parent association like this:

```
headers.setContentType(new MediaType("text", "uri-list"));
...
restTemplate.put(selfLink.toString()+"/parent", entity, parentGenreURI );
```

I get a 500 Internal Server error on the client side, but the actual error is swallowed on the REST API side, and there's nothing in the logs.

If I try to PATCH the URI itself with the parent's uri like this:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
...
Map map = ImmutableMap.of("parent", parentGenreLink);
restTemplate.exchange(selfLink.toString()+"/parent", HttpMethod.PATCH, entity, String.class, map);
```

I get a 400 Bad Request error on the client, and on the server I get

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read an object of type class Genre
>   from the request!; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read payload!; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map
>   due to end-of-input

which makes me think this is the right way to do it, but I'm just doing it wrong.

Could anyone provide some guidance on this? Every example I've seen just uses curl, which doesn't help me that much :)

There's a few similarly answered questions on SO, but most of them either point to documentation that no longer exists, or has such simple objects all the content gets dumped in a map.

Comment: A little more Infos like Entity-, Controller- and Config-Classes were helpful, could you post?

Comment: Could you solve your problem? If so you help us by posting your solution.

Comment: Can you post your rest client code, your controller and some debug log. There is hardly enough information to form a summary.... Secondly, if your client is complaining of unknown values, I know what to do, but ofcourse I would require to see some code.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the small amount of code you've posted and the error you've received I think you're calling your service in the wrong way.

I'm taking the second call as the example here, but since I think you're doing the same mistake in both calls the solution to the first error should be analogous.

If we look at the documentation for the [`RestTemplate.exchange`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map-) you're calling we can see that it wants the following arguments:

1. The URL to call
2. The method to use
3. The *HttpEntity* to send as the request
4. The class of the response
5. The parameter values to replace in the URL

Where I think you're going wrong is on arguments 3 and 5. It seems to me that you're trying to send the JSON payload

```
{
  "parent": "someGenre"
}
```

But what you're actually doing is telling the template to replace any occurence of the string *{parent}* (an URL parameter placeholder) in the URL with the value of *parentGenreLink*.

What you probably want to do is to set the map as the body on the *HttpEntity* instead and not pass any URL parameters:

```
// Create the body
Map map = ImmutableMap.of("parent", parentGenreLink);

// Create the headers
Headers headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

// Create the HTTP Entity
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

// Make the call without any URL parameters
restTemplate.exchange(selfLink.toString()+"/parent", HttpMethod.PATCH, entity, String.class);
```

Note that for this to work you have to have a message converter capable of (de)serialising JSON set up on the template:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Comment: I actually figured this out last week and your answer is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Beyond what @Raniz suggested, another way to do it is:

```
HttpHeaders reqHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
reqHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, new MediaType("text", "uri-list").toString());
HttpEntity<String> reqEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(category0link.getHref(), reqHeaders);
ResponseEntity<String> string = template.exchange(widget0link.getHref(),  HttpMethod.PUT, reqEntity, String.class, ImmutableMap.of());
```